# How does vite know where index.html is located in a NEW react app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, vite

vite.config.js

```
import vite, { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    //root: './public',
    publicDir: 'public',
    plugins: [react()],
})
```

I created a new React app and  installed vite.

My index.html file is inside 'public'.

How do i get vite/npm to recognize this?

I keep getting a HTTP 404 message.

Comment: You should consider moving `index.html`: https://vitejs.dev/guide/#index-html-and-project-root

Comment: @jabaa I saw this but can't figure out how to make vite work. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Move the file into the root of your project.

Comment: it didn't work for me

Comment: Maybe there is an additional problem in your project.